# Is it possible to determine the Probability of Error for the classifier form the ROC curve at a specific point?

Tags: probability, classification, roc

Given a classifier with an ROC curve at a specific point, say: (FNR = 0.01, FPR = 0.1).

- Is it possible to determine the Probability of Error for the classifier at this point?

Comment: Probability of error being one minus the accuracy?

Comment: @Dave yes, exactly $$P(err) = \frac{(FP+FN)}{All}$$